# testng gives noclassdeffound error when running in command line in linux

Tags: testng

i am getting the following error while running a testNG program in command line in linux machine.

echo $CLASSPATH
(confirmed that testng jar is in CLASSPATH)

then ran the below (testng.xml and the testclass is in current directory)

bash-2.05b# java org.testng.TestNG testNG.xml

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

i read some threads that spoke of adding jcommander class but those are when running from ant.....not when running from command line..... any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry. seems like this was my mistake.

classpath didnt have the right folder for the jcommander jar. this seems to have fixed this issue.